# Did the judges have a tendency to favor a poor person in the court of law?

Tags: exodus

> Exodus 23:2 “Do not follow the crowd in doing wrong. When you give testimony in a lawsuit, do not pervert justice by siding with the crowd

This is a fair warning because it could be the wrong crowd.

> 3 and do not show favoritism to a poor person in a lawsuit.

This warning sounds strange. Did the judges have a tendency to favor a poor person in the court of law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injunction in Ex 23:2, "do not show favoritism to a poor", should be balanced by another instruction in V6, "You shall not deny justice to the poor".

Ellicott summarizes the situation well -

> (3) Neither shalt thou countenance a poor man in his cause.—We must
> not “pervert judgment” either in favour of the rich or of the poor.
> Justice must hold her scales even, and be proof equally against a
> paltry fear of the rich and a weak compassion for the indigent. The
> cause alone is to be considered, not the persons. (Comp. Leviticus
> 19:15.)

Similarly, the Pulpit commentary says this -

> Verse 3. - Neither shalt thou countenance a poor man in his cause.
> After the many precepts in favour of the poor, this injunction
> produces a sort of shock. But it is to be understood as simply
> forbidding any undue favouring of the poor because they are poor, and
> so as equivalent to the precept in Leviticus 19:15, "Thou shalt not
> respect the person of the poor." In courts of justice, strict justice
> is to be rendered, without any leaning either towards the rich, or
> towards the poor. To lean either way is to pervert judgment. Exodus
> 23:3